# Golang - Why does this function change the input argument?

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang and I come from PHP background. I have a bit of trouble understanding some of the core functionalities at times.

Specifically, right now I'm building a Hearths game and I've created a CardStack type, that has some convenient methods one might use in a card stack (read: player's hand, discard pile...) such as `DrawCards(...)`, `AppendCards(...)`...

**The problem** I have is that the function `func (c* CardStack) DrawCards(cards []deck.Card) ([]deck.Card, error) {...}` changes the argument `cards []deck.Card` and I cannot figure out why or how to avoid this.

This is my CardStack:

```
type CardStack struct {
    cards []deck.Card
}
```

This is my `DrawCards` method:

```
func (c *CardStack) DrawCards(cards []deck.Card) ([]deck.Card, error) {
    return c.getCardsSlice(cards, true)
}

// Returns cards that are missing
func (c *CardStack) getCardsSlice(cards []deck.Card, rm bool) ([]deck.Card, error) {
    var err error
    var returnc = []deck.Card{}
    for _, card := range cards {
        fmt.Println("BEFORE c.findCard(cards): ")
        deck.PrintCards(cards) // In my example this will print out {Kc, 8d}, which is what I expect it to be
        _, err = c.findCard(card, rm) // AFTER THIS LINE THE cards VAR IS CHANGED
        fmt.Println("AFTER c.findCard(cards): ")
        deck.PrintCards(cards) // In my example this will print out {8d, 8d}, which is not at all what I expected
        if err != nil {
            return returnc, err
        }
    }
    return returnc, nil
}

// Expects string like "Ts" or "2h" (1. face 2. suit)
func (c *CardStack) findCard(cc deck.Card, rm bool) (deck.Card, error) {
    for i, card := range c.GetCards() {
        if cc == card {
            return c.cardByIndex(i, rm)
        }
    }
    return deck.Card{}, fmt.Errorf("Card not found")
}

func (c *CardStack) cardByIndex(n int, rm bool) (deck.Card, error) {
    if n > len(c.GetCards()) {
        return deck.Card{}, fmt.Errorf("Index out of bounds")
    }

    card := c.GetCards()[n]
    if rm {
        c.SetCards(append(c.GetCards()[:n], c.GetCards()[n+1:]...))
    }
    return card, nil
}
```

To explain a bit more - specifically the `findCard(...)` method that gets called in `getCardsSlice` messes with the original value (I've added comments to indicate where it happens).

If it's of any help, this is part of my `main()` method that I use for debugging:

```
// ...
ss, _ := cards.SubStack(1, 3) // ss now holds {Kc, 8d}
ss.Print() // Prints {Kc, 8d}
cards.Print() // Prints {5c, Kc, 8d} (assigned somewhere up in the code)
cards.DrawCards(ss) // Draws {Kc, 8d} from {5c, Kc, 8d}
cards.Print() // Prints {5c} - as expected
ss.Print() // Prints {8d, 8d} - ???
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I go about doing this.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

**Edit**:

The whole CardStack file: http://pastebin.com/LmhryfGc

**Edit2**:

I was going to put it on github sooner or later (was hoping after the code looks semi-ok), here it is - https://github.com/d1am0nd/hearths-go/tree/cardstack/redo

Comment: We can't show you the specific problem with a complete example, but it looks like you're passing around multiple slices pointing to the same array. Chances are `GetCards` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: I'm more than happy to update you with anything you need. Give me a min and I'll edit my original post

Comment: @JimB I've created a Pastebin with my card stack. `GetCards` is just `return c.cards`. If there is anything else you think could help let me know

Comment: `deck.PrintCards` is not seen in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the value of `cards` in `DrawCards` is a sub-slice of the `CardsStack.cards` slice, which is referencing values in the same backing array.

When you call `findCard` and remove a card from the `CardStack.cards` slice, you are manipulating the same array that the `cards` argument is using.

When you want a copy of a slice, you need to allocate a new slice and copy each element. To do this in your example, you could:

```
ssCopy := make([]deck.Card, len(ss))
copy(ssCopy, ss)
cards.DrawCards(ssCopy)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of the help! So judging by that my [`SubStack`](https://github.com/d1am0nd/hearths-go/blob/cardstack/redo/hearths/cardstack.go#L120) method is screwing me over? Because (if I understand correctly) it returns the reference to the same array, rather than creating a copy. (also I've put it on github so whole source is visible now)

Comment: Yes, if the intent if SubStack is to return a new slice, then you need to allocate one and copy the value (or possibly do it in SetCards. It's up to you to determine the specific semantics of the methods here)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help and simple explanation!